# Валяная или валянная обувь?

Tags: орфография, суффиксы

*Валян(н)ая обувь* (валенки), — одна Н, или две? Я больше склоняюсь к одной.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Корректно: *Валяная обувь.*
Нет, это не валенки Или не только валенки. Это именно валяная обувь, прежде всего - сапоги. Разница в том, что сапоги эти имеют мягкое, обтягивающее ногу голенище и гораздо тоньше. 
Если нет зависимых слов, то "валяный" - прилагательное и, следовательно, пишется через одно Н.

Answer (score 0):

В суффиксе -ян- имён прилагательных пишется одно Н. Исключения хорошо известны: стеклянный, деревянный, оловянный.

Comment: Хорошо бы еще уметь доказывать, что это именно прилагательное, 
да и отличать суффикс от букв на стыке корня и суффикса.

Comment: Если бы это было причастие, то оно образовывалось бы с помощью суффикса -енн-.
Валяный образовано отглагола валять скорее всего с помощью суффикса -н-, а не -ян-, -я-  - глагольный суффикс. Видимо, приведенное мной правило про суффикс -ян- здесь не работает. Но и стык корня и суффикса тут тоже не при чём.

Comment: *"Если бы это было причастие, то оно образовывалось бы с помощью суффикса -енн-"*  
Не факт. Тут есть некая грамматическая лакуна, причастие от прилагательного не всегда отличается иначе как орфографически, а это, как понимаете, порочный круг.В данном случае "валенный" словарями не виксируется, а зависимых слов можно навешать сколь угодно много: "валяный из овечьей шерсти работкинками в течение месяцев..."   Но не буду сейчас эту тему поднимать, пусть причастие будет валенный. Вопрос не снимается, только запутывается: "Как правильно: валенный или валяный?", прилагательное тут или причастие?

Comment: *Валяный образовано отглагола валять скорее всего с помощью суффикса -н-, а не -ян-, -я- - глагольный суффикс.*
Тоже не факт. Это вопрос выбора подхода, синхронического или диахронического, детям, кажется, это дают как корень (поправьте, если вру, я не спец по ЕГЭ). Но это опять-таки столь не важно. Пусть будет стык двух суффиксов. Это все равно не одно и то же, что и один суффикс "янн".   
Короче, я никак не могу согласиться с рекомендацией решать орфографическое затруднение через решение ещё менее очевидной проблемы выбора части речи.

Answer (score -1):

Я абсолютно точно знаю, что это отглагольное прилагательное, образованное от глагола ***валять*** при помощи суффикса -н-.
*Стеклянный, оловянный, деревянный* здесь вовсе не при чем, так как это отыменные прилагательные.